# Scroll down to element on page load

Tags: jquery, html, razor, jquery-animate, url-parameters

I am trying to take a parameter and convert it into an element and the scroll down to that element on page load, but it doesn't seem to work. My JavaScript is this:

```
function ParameterJump(param) {
    var $target = ""

    if (param == "stjerneplus") 
        $target = $("#box-0");
    else if (param == "lounge")
        $target = $("#box-1");
    else if (param == "rejse")
        $target = $("#box-3");
    else
        $target = $("#box-3");

    $('html, body').delay(1000).animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 1500, 'easeOutCirc' });
}

ParameterJump("@Request.QueryString["link"]");
```

The site is www.stjerneplus.dk

The "param" will be taken from the "link" parameter that will be in a URL in a newsletter.

So there will be 7 links and those 7 links will have a different value in the link parameter corresponding to the element that stjerneplus.dk should scroll down to on page load. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Check the console, you have a syntax error in your `animate()` call. Fix that and it should work fine.

Comment: What if you name your boxes not like `box-N` but like your parameters? It will be a kind of semantic approach and in this case you won't need those `if's`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - console isn't giving me any errors.

Comment: You have an erroneous closing brace (`}`) after `easeOutCirc`.

Comment: Arh... thank you - but fixing that did'nt do much